# Livequery fires click no matter where the user clicks in the document

Tags: jquery-plugins, livequery

I have replaced the traditional select/option form elements with a nifty little popup window when a triggering image is clicked. The page is for accounting purposes and so multiple line items are to be expected. I've written the javascript that will dynamically generate new line item select/option elements. When the page loads, the initial set of choices loads and the user can click on them, get a pop up with some choices, choose one and then the box closes. The move to the next choice and so on and so forth. I've added livequery to my code for those dynamic elements. However... the livequery("click"...) seems to fire no matter where the user clicks on the page. Very frustrating.

I've read on here how great "live()" is in jQuery 1.3, but I am not able to upgrade fully to jquery 1.3 because a custom JS file depends on 1.2, so using live() is out of the question, however I have invoked the livequery() plugin and I really need to understand if I'm using it correctly.

I will post partial code. There's just way too much to post all of it.

Basically, I'm searching for divs starting with "bubble" and then a number afterwards. Then run the event on each them. Only bubble1 is static, 2 and up are dynamic. Am I missing the whole usage of livequery?

```
>$jb('div[id^="bubble"]').each(function () {
> var divid = $jb('div[id^="bubble"]').filter(":first").attr("id");
>var pref = "bubble";
>var i = divid.substring((pref.length));
>var trigger = $jb('#trigger' + i, this);
>var popup = $jb('#pop'+ i, this).css('opacity', 0);
>var selectedoption = $jb('selectedOption' + i, this);
>var selectedtext = $jb('selectedOptionText' + i, this);
>$jb([trigger.get(0), popup.get(0)]).livequery("click",
> function () {
>//alert(i);
// code removed for brevity (just the contents of the popups)
>});
```

Answer (score 0):

Live works by using event delegation. A click event is attached to the body, and anytime something is clicked the selector is tested against the target. If it passes the selector test it calls the function (thus simulating a click event).

You probably want something like this:

```
$('div[id^="bubble"]').livequery("click", function() {
    var divId = $(this).attr("id");
    var i = divId.substring("bubble".length);
    var trigger = $("#trigger" + i, this);
    var popup = $("#pop" + i, this).css("opacity", 0);
    // alert(i);
}
```