# jquery livequery event triggered on EVERYTHING, not just selected element

Tags: jquery, click, livequery

I am attempting to use livequery.  I unfortunately am stuck using jquery 1.2.6.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.sort').livequery('click', function(event) {
        alert('hello');
    });
});
```

If I click ANYWHERE in the document, I get the alert 'hello'.

What exactly is wrong there?  Is it some bug with jQ1.2.6 and livequery 1.1.1?

This same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858293/livequery-fires-click-no-matter-where-the-user-clicks-in-the-document) but the question wasn't clear, and the answer didn't help.

Comment: Every click somehow seems to match your selector 'a.sort', can you give the link an id and test it directly on that?

Comment: I changed it to $('#djsfhaskdfas').livequery(...).
It still fires the event.  It seems it doesn't even matter what selector I put in there.

Comment: This answer is now out-of-date. Curious readers should look at http://api.jquery.com/on instead of `.livequery`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shucks...

livequery 1.1.1 is **NOT** compatible with jQuery 1.2.6.  It only works with jQuery 1.3+

If you need to use a version < 1.3, then livequery 1.0.3 is the latest one that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Use the rel attribute:

```
$('a[rel*=sort]') 
.livequery('click', function(event) { 
    alert('test'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this: $(document).ready(function() {
It is triggered for whole document, rather than requested element.